# How to handle For each condition in Data weaver: Mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el

I'm getting struggle in looping the entries in data weaver. Below is the Input and the expected response.
   Not sure how to make loop(I need to get `RecordEntry` and each entry with 'IndividualEntry') .

Input xml : Record entry tag  in input xml is 3, but I might get many. So need to make a loop as dynamic.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Records>
  <storenumber />
  <calculated>false</calculated>
  <subTotal>12</subTotal>
  <RecordsEntries>
    <RecordEntry>
      <deliverycharge>30.0</deliverycharge>
      <entryNumber>8</entryNumber>
      <Value>true</Value>
    </RecordEntry>
    <RecordEntry>
      <deliverycharge>20.0</deliverycharge>
      <entryNumber>7</entryNumber>
      <Value>false</Value>
    </RecordEntry>
    <RecordEntry>
      <deliverycharge>1.0</deliverycharge>
      <entryNumber>6</entryNumber>
      <Value>false</Value>
    </RecordEntry>
  </RecordsEntries>
</Records>
```

Expected Response ( I'm expecting the below response)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<orders>
  <order>
    <StoreID />
    <Total>false</Total>
    <IndividualEntry>
      <Number>8</Number>
      <DeliverCharge>30.0</DeliverCharge>
    </IndividualEntry>
    <IndividualEntry>
      <Number>7</Number>
      <DeliverCharge>20.0</DeliverCharge>
    </IndividualEntry>
    <IndividualEntry>
      <Number>6</Number>
      <DeliverCharge>1.0</DeliverCharge>
    </IndividualEntry>
  </order>
</orders>
```

My Data weaver Transformation as below

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
---
{ 
  orders: {
    order: {
      StoreID:payload.Records.storenumber,
      Total: payload.Records.calculated,
      IndividualEntry: payload.Records.RecordsEntries.*RecordEntry map {
        Number:$.entryNumber,
        DeliverCharge:$.deliverycharge
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Currently I'm getting response as below ( I don't know how to make each Record entry as a `IndividualEntry` tag, and also here `element` tag is added in extra which is not required in my case)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<orders>
  <order>
    <StoreID />
    <Total>false</Total>
    <IndividualEntry>
      <element>
        <Number>8</Number>
        <DeliverCharge>30.0</DeliverCharge>
      </element>
      <element>
        <Number>7</Number>
        <DeliverCharge>20.0</DeliverCharge>
      </element>
      <element>
        <Number>6</Number>
        <DeliverCharge>1.0</DeliverCharge>
      </element>
    </IndividualEntry>
  </order>
</orders>
```

Could any one help me in fix this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
orders: {
  order: {
      StoreID: payload.Records.storenumber,
      Total: payload.Records.calculated,
      (payload.Records.RecordsEntries.*RecordEntry map {
        IndividualEntry: {
        Number:$.entryNumber,
        DeliverCharge:$.deliverycharge
        }
      })
  }
}
```

Inside an `object` when you put an expression between parenthesis that returns an `array of key-value pairs` it is evaluated and used to fill the `object`.

See section`5.1.3. Dynamic elements` in https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/dataweave

Comment: Please note the key here is to use the map function on an expression that returns the desired collection.  In this example, it is payload.Records.RecordsEntries.*RecordEntry .

Comment: Perfect!!  Working fine. Tried multiple things, but haven't tried with Parenthesis. Thank you for the details!!